# How to deselect using box select?

Tags: shortcut

How do I deselect using the box select tool? I have read about middle mouse button and some other shortcuts but they don't work for me.

Comment: I use to have a mouse with a scroll wheel, but it had no middle mouse click. This might be your issue.

Comment: @CharlesL I do have middle mouse click. I can move the camera with it.

Comment: Are you middle mouse clicking and dragging? You have to hold down middle mouse the entire time.

Comment: @CharlesL I hold it down

Comment: Try using emulate 3 button mouse and see if that works.

Comment: Does your deselect work when you use Circle Select (C) and the middle mouse button?

Comment: Remember *not* to hold down the B for box selecting. You press *and release* B and you enter a box selection mode... and from there you should be able to deselect with MMB.

Comment: Just press A dude :) I mean you have to press it a few times but it does deselect ;)

Answer (score 31):

If using v2.68 (revision [57577](https://projects.blender.org/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=bf-blender&revision=57577)+), you can do the following:

- Press <kbd>B</kbd>,
- Use <kbd>LMB</kbd> and drag to form the (de)selection rectangle,
- hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while releasing <kbd>LMB</kbd>.

[image: Demonstration of the above steps.]

Comment: Didn't work. It just selected

Comment: I am trying to select some faces after selecting. Instead of that, it selects other vertices that are also in the box. It doesn't deselect anything.

Comment: please update your Question with more information then.

Comment: OOPS I meant deselect instead of select in my other comment

Comment: i'm not sure why that doesn't work for you guys, I use it frequently. (i'm still on build r57660, 2.67.1)

Comment: Works for me, even when I don't have *Emulate 3 Button Mouse* set.

Comment: works for me, too. (With and without *Emulate 3 button Mouse*)

Comment: Is there a better way to do this yet?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Blender 3.1.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like your issue is an issue with the middle mouse button on your mouse. The following steps do not require a working middle mouse button to deselect:

1. Go to your user preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>)
2. Go to the *Input* tab
3. In the left sidebar, check the *Emulate 3 Button Mouse* checkbox
4. Whenever instructions say to use the  middle mouse button, you can now use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + *Left Click* instead.

To use box select to deselect use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + *Left Click* and drag.

Answer (score 4):

As described on the [Blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Selecting#Rectangular_or_Border_Select):

1. <kbd>B</kbd> to enter border selection.
2. Drag the deselection rectangular using your middle mouse button.

Comment: Thanks, but middle mouse button doesn't work, I already said that in the question.

Comment: @Jop It does here. I thought it unlikely that you had found a bug and suspected you were just doing it wrong.

Comment: @jop, you'll have to use alt instead. Go to your user prefs, go to input and check "Emulate 3 button mouse". Then replace alt-left click for middle click.

Comment: At the time of writing this comment, this answer worked by default for the latest Blender version of the time.

Answer (score 3):

I found that the easies solution is to just invert the selection and afterwards invert it again.
This works with all selection tools and you just need to press Ctrl-I