# Cell fracture deletes pieces of model

Tags: modeling

I have a quick question about cell fracture.  I am trying to shatter a bridge which is a bit large and cell fracture is doing a nice job.  However, my shattered bridge is missing parts.  The fracture is missing most of the top of the bridge peices, which makes it already look broken.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried splitting it into parts and shattering those separately? I had the same problem a while ago, and that was the only solution.

Comment: @GregZaal No, but thank you I will try soon.

Comment: Split the mesh into smaller pieces and shatter them individually.

Comment: If you'd like to have that as an answer, you'll have to be a little more detailed. Future googlers may have no idea what that means.

Comment: @Dan Could you please undelete his answer, I'm worried about the unanswered stats.

Comment: @stacker We want good, detailed, quality answers that others can benefit from. No use have every question answered if all the answers are vague oneliners..

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6738/599

Comment: @gandalf3 thanks, it is unlikely that we get a better answer so I voted to this as a dup.