# Cell fracture doesnt work well

Tags: modeling, mesh, add-on

I'm trying to fracture my statue object. I looked everywhere  but couldnt make the fracture work well.
this is the blend file http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30082
anyone can help me?
Thank you!!!

Comment: I made an example file by boolean joining the different parts of your mesh. It's not perfect, but maybe it will help.. http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30084

Comment: Wow, This is amazing!. Can you elaborate a little how you did it?
Thank you

Comment: @gandalf3 Did you do that by hand? if you didn't, could you please show us how!

Comment: @GiantCowFilms I've edited my answer [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6739/599) with some examples :)