# Using difference modifier on two objects doesn't always work

Tags: mesh

I want to use the difference boolean modifier to stamp in shapes on this lime. However it does not work for some of the characters. Only some of the radicals (pieces) are cut out. The picture shows one such example: the lower right J shaped piece is missing.

Is this the best way to approach this? The end result I am seeking is Chinese characters written on it.

[image]

Comment: Select the text object, go into edit mode. Remove the doubles using W -> remove doubles, than recalc the normals (make sure you are in edit mode) Ctrl + N

Comment: The problem persists. It's not a text object but a curve. It says Curve.004 in the list in the upper right. It said removed 0 vertices when removing doubles. I recalculated both outside and inside normals.

Comment: can you upload the blend file?

Comment: Sure! https://www.dropbox.com/s/21gajqvyfuzlg46/NaotanLemon.blend

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5140/599

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the boolean operation to work properly you need to fix the mesh first.

1. Select the text object
2. Go into edit mode, <kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. Select all, <kbd>A</kbd>
4. Remove the doubles, <kbd>W</kbd> -> Remove Doubles
5. Fix the normals, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> N

Once you do this the boolean operation will work properly

[image]

Comment: I was so excited to see you did it, but it doesn't work for me. Why? Are you running Blender 2.7?

Comment: I am using blender 2.7

Comment: Hmm the only thing I can think of is that the "select the text object" stage went wrong. When I remove doubles, I always get the message 0 vertices removed. How many vertices are removed when you do it?

Comment: about 600 vertex were removed.

Comment: @SwimBikeRun you need to select all vertices before running the remove doubles command

Comment: Ah I got it now. Thanks. The 3D print turned out great :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that applying rotation, scale and location to the object that you're trying to apply the boolean modifier to fixes this problem.