# Boolean difference modifier merges two object

Tags: modifiers

i want to use difference in Boolean modifier but actually the result are like it is merged, i want a hole inside a custom shape. beore using difference:
[image: before difference is applied]

and here is the result after difference is applied, it is like the cylinder is merged instead of subtract:
[image: after the difference is applied. i moved the shape so that now two cylinders are visible]

i have tried this link suggestions:
[Using difference modifier on two objects doesn't always work](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7911/using-difference-modifier-on-two-objects-doesnt-always-work)

i am a total beginner so if i am making a stupid mistake please accept my appologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have consistent [normals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) on your objects - normals determine what is outside and what is inside.

To recalculate normals go into Edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), select all geometry (<kbd>A</kbd>) and perform "Recalculate normals outside" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>N</kbd>)

After all your pieces have correct normals (you will also notice consistent shading of all objects) - booleans will work as expected.

You might also want to set the object that you do boolean with as wireframe (you do that under Object Display options):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It persists after computing the normals. When enabling overlays->FaceOrientation all shapes turn blue. So the normals seem OK. Nonetheless, it merged instead of removing the intersection.
I was able to fix it via EditMode->a(select all)->Mesh-Cleanup->MergeByDistance. It seems that I did some extrude operations that created duplicate vertices without me realizing it. The MergeByDistance removed them. After that, the boolean difference worked fine.

I'm using Blender 3.1.0 and the shapes have less than 100 vertices.