# Boolean difference modifier does not remove a part

Tags: modifiers

I'm new to Blender and got the following problem.

As stated in multiple threads on this board the functionality of the boolean difference misbehaves. 
I want to reach the following result: 
[image]
Instead I get this:

[image]

I also checked and tried the solutions as described in these threads.

([Using difference modifier on two objects doesn't always work](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7911/using-difference-modifier-on-two-objects-doesnt-always-work))

([Boolean difference modifier merges two object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64371/boolean-difference-modifier-merges-two-object?noredirect=1&lq=1))

But none of these worked as I always get "Removed 0 Vertices" when I use the command "Remove Doubles".

Right now I am using the v2.79 of Blender.
Also the file for this car is uploaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wals3y77v20fy4h/thecarstackexchangehelp.blend?dl=0).

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out on that. Maybe some other people have the same issue...

Comment: Recalculate normals on both objects and use the Carve solver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the car boy and add boolean modifier

Select the wheel as object

In the operation select intersect & change from BMesh to Carver

Apply the modifier

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apperently the following approach is also working. Thanks to [Jerryno](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/7777/jerryno)s answer I tried another approach.

Instead of taking the boolean modifier onto the car, I took the joined Cylinders and filled in the settings for the modifier as following:

[image]