# Boolean Difference Modifier only adds

Tags: modifiers, normals

[In this Video](https://youtu.be/d4JAIP6ffjs) you can see how applying the difference modifier only results in merging the object into the other object.

I tried doing the thing in [Boolean difference modifier merges two object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64371/boolean-difference-modifier-merges-two-object) but it didnt help.
[image]

Comment: The post in the second link has inconsistent normals for one of the objects (also the most often reason of swapped Boolean operations). Did you try follow the answer there i.e. enter Edit mode for your objects, select all and press Ctrl+N?

Comment: tried, doesnt work..

Comment: This happens a lot with me too, last time I checked for the problem and found out that I didn't remove the double vertices on the mesh. You could try going in edit mode and removing the doubles.

Comment: You could at least show some screenshots of the mesh. How is anyone supposed to guess what doesn't work with that object? Apart from screenshots create a small version of the blend with problem object and share it here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and [edit] your post with resulting link

Comment: edited the original post

Comment: Move cutter object (Cube.009 in your setup) a bit down (0.0001 Blender Unit will be more than enough). Right now objects are lowpoly cubes without any supporting geometry in that area and their bottom faces are on the same Z position. Boolean can't decide where is the cutter and hence inverts normals. As a aworkaround change Solver in Boolean settings to Carve, this one seems to work better in this situation