# My boolean/difference operation didn't work

Tags: modifiers

I'm relatively new to Blender and I'm trying to apply the Boolean modifier to substract channels from the water bottle holder.

[image]

I added the  the Boolean modifier to the Cylinder, with Difference as the operation, and the target object as the Plane... But when I removed the plane it had not affected the cylinder.

So I read some advices from similar cases on Stackexchange (flip faces), but the boolean still does not work for me.

Comment: The normals are still oriented wrongly for the Plane object (one around the cylinder), use Ctrl+N in edit mode, also it's not closed, there is the opening at the top part of the mesh, fill it with face. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7911/using-difference-modifier-on-two-objects-doesnt-always-work and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/boolean-modifier-not-working

Comment: I did something wrong with the screw... It was leaving lines on the cylinder... so I redid the screw and it worked... thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

The modifiers are designed so you can change them later; if you changed the target object, it would change the effect. Similarly, if you *delete* the target object, it will remove the effect!

What you need to do is to **apply** the modifier. There should be an Apply button just beneath the 'add modifier' popup.

Note that this will make it impossible to remove the effect again later (except manually, of course), but if you're deleting the plane anyway, it should be what you need.