# Boolean Subtraction Problem

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Hello Mighty Stackexchange, I'm trying to subtract some cylinders (place for LED's) from an object.
It looks like this before subtraction.
[image: Before Subtraction]

But when done subtracting, I'm left with this.
Info on modifier, Solver = BMesh, Overlap Threshold = 0.000001.
[image: After Subtraction]

I'm kinda new to blender, I studied autoCAD in school, so blender isnt entirely new. But I'm still clueless on what is going wrong, I've searched but havent found anyone who encountered the same/similar problem.

I'd be happy to give more data/settings if required/asked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*I've searched but havent found anyone who encountered the same/similar problem.*" https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=boolean+subtract

Comment: booleans issues are quite common here, we can help with your specific setup, but you should your file on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then edit your question and paste the provided link

Answer (score 1):

[Using difference modifier on two objects doesn't always work](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7911/using-difference-modifier-on-two-objects-doesnt-always-work)

This one helped me reduce the problem so that I could manually finish the last.
Thanks for the help. :)

Removing doubles and fixing the normals. More instructions at the link.