# Make a mould/Remove inner geometry for touching objects (including ones self)

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I'm using Blender 2.7 and new to the whole thing (Blender is immensely brain intensive) and I have managed to produce I model I like. My next step is to put a shell around it, then slice it in half to make a mould but the boolean stuff I did didn't want to work as expected so I tried some slicing, however the bits I joined have internal geometry that I don't want.

Hopefully an image:

[image: my model]

I have 3 objects, the loop top left, the dangle bit in the middle and a single outer object that loops round and intersects with itself. The object has been through netfabb and is a complete shell all round. All the meshes were created using an array and end caps.

Originally, I tried creating a cube to wrap the bottom half of the joined heart component mesh and then added a boolean "difference" but it failed, just saying it couldn't do it. I tried it with each individual mesh, well the first one, but it didn't do what I wanted - in object view it looked good, but then the manual said something about adding a subsurf... which when I tried to do just made the cube round and a real mess around what was removed.

So my next thought was to split along the XY axis and make a face with the cube. but when I sliced the object, there was a lot of inner geometry that I couldn't remove properly - especially where the outer loop contacts itself.

I tried the remesh modifier on the joined object but that fails quite soon and doesn't even get close to the shape.

I tried a boolean on the components. I added a difference one to the outer loop and the dangle, this seemed ok, I think I could then delete the internal faces and somehow join the edges of the mesh. I then added another one on the outer and the loop, then blender crashed.

Possibly an immediate fixer-upper would be to reduce the complexity on the loop top left?

Assuming this works how would I then delete the internals from the looping round on itself.

Can anyone help me or point me at a tutorial. I will reiterate - I am a brainally challenged noob without the blender cribsheet. So, please can you suggest keystrokes as well :)

Many thanks.
Nigel

Comment: Hi Nigel, unfortunately, this is a known bug in Blender. You can read about this in the answer [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5140/cannot-execute-boolean-operation-when-subtracting-several-spheres-and-cylinder).

Comment: @ThomBlairIII That example is working just fine for me in 2.70 with the new ngon support for boolean modifiers.. @ NigelJohnsen Could you upload a .blend? It's hard to determine if things will work or not without testing on the same mesh.