# Trying to use Boolean (difference) Modifier on a ring design and its not working correctly?

Tags: modifiers

Okay so I followed this  [you tube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e16c8uaCwzY&feature=kp) to make this ring and they way it is done on the video isn't working for me, I am not sure what the problem is. I have tried everything I found on the internet,!
advice from author [image]

activating the 3D print tool addon and running the  solid to check for problems, 
which it is saying I have some non manifold edges,!
[image] which are there bc those sides do not have faces because I used a mirror modifier on x and y to complete my basic shape, but I don't know how that could be the problem with the boolean because that is how its done on the video and it works?? [image: my results with boolean(difference) modifier] I have done everything i can think of, even rearranging the modifiers,results from the video [image: results from the video]
I have checked all the normals [image]
I'm out of things to try, please help?

Comment: Could you upload your .blend? It's hard to say in this case what the problem is without fiddling with the file..

Comment: I would love to, just have no idea where to upload it on this site? Help please?lol

Comment: You can't currently, instead you'll have to use [pasteall](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/) or something and put the link here.

Comment: Okay here it is thank you so much for your help, I learned something new! http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30443

Answer (score 1):

[Boolean operations sometimes fail](https://developer.blender.org/T37659) when vertices between the two objects line up exactly.
You can work around this by moving one of the objects a very small amount.

[**Example .blend**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30445)

Also see [“Cannot execute boolean operation” when subtracting several spheres and cylinders from cube](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5140/599)

Comment: Thanks a million gandalf3, I finally got it!! Here I thought it was a setting or something...lol

Answer (score 0):

I too am building up a ring and ran into this very problem.

Here are some things to check:

- Check your mesh for doubles

  - select all
  - (Blender 2.8) `Mesh` > `Clean Up` > `Merge By Distance`
- Check that your meshes are Manifold

  - This one has usually been my culprit
  - Go to edit mode
  - Select none
  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>
  - This will highlight any non-manifold geometry
  - you will then need to find a way to fix it (google is your friend)
  - in my case, it was being created in previous boolean modifications

**Tip:**  When doing boolean modifiers, I have found that the `Carve` setting helped create Manifold geometry. This helps if you are doing successive boolean modifications, since I've found that non-manifold geometry behaves poorly with subsequent Boolean Modifiers.

Good luck on your journey, I hope it goes well!