# Blender Boolean modifier: Difference behaves like union

Tags: modifiers

Attached is an example in which *difference* modifier behaves like *union*.

Is this is a bug (I think so)?
See [this .blender example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3xskN0a8UruRjlQSmtrYjR5Vjg/view?usp=sharing) in which I tried to use boolean modifier difference (*Child* is subtracted from *Parent* so modifier is on *Parent*)

#### Behavior

In both, the expected behavior is *difference*, but actual behavior is *union*

#### Failed attempts

Before posting here I:

1. Checked that my objects were manifolds
2. Checked that normals are pointing outwards (Edit Mode -> Select All -> Ctrl N)
3. No shared faces between any two objects
4. Removing doubles (double vertices)
5. [Converting to triangles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21304/cannot-execute-boolean-operation)

I have read extensively on StackExchange and other forums, and watched guides, including [this very relevant guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JAZsJv7vUE).

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Blender Developer forum [(See this bug)](https://developer.blender.org/T45161),

Comment: I usually try to avoid the boolean modifier because it has bugs, I'll try and take a look a your .blend file later, if I don't see anything wrong with how you're setting up the boolean, I'll show you some (better imo) alternatives to the boolean modifier.

Comment: Tips on removing doubles in [BlenderArtist](http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-199960.html)

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5140/599, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14085/599, and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7910/599. Also see this [bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T37659).

Comment: I appended the child to a new .blend (so I just have the child by itself) and when I try to move it, it won't move.  Is the object complex and it's not responding right away (lag), or is there another problem.  I looked at the child to see if it's manifold, and CTRL-ALT-SHIFT-M shows it as manifold; however, I have another tool (3D Printing), which tries to fix non-manifold, and does nothing when an object is manifold (or so I've discovered so far on other projects), and that tool butchers it up, which means the 3D printing Non-manifold tool is treating the child like it's non-manifold.

Comment: I done some simple boolean modifications on some things, and I've discovered if the faces are perfectly aligned, meaning a face of A and a face of B are aligned such that there is no gap the boolean won't work.  But, moving one face such that it overlaps by even a small amount, the boolean works. Usually the error caused by this is small enough in the overall design it makes no difference, even in printing, which is mostly what I design for, right now.  Is this what you meant @gandalf3

Comment: OK, disregard why the child won't resize or move, it's locked.  My apologies, I never used the locks before; but I finally noticed that it's locked and that's why I can't transform the child. lol  Sorry.

Comment: I think I found it; when I appended only the parent object, I discoverd that there is a child embedded in it; When I removed the second child, I was able to boolean difference a child object, and it worked.  Because everything was locked, it was impossible to see the second child object as it matched perfectly with the parent.  I'm not sure why I didn't see it in the Outliner.   Yes, in the original file, open an outliner window and expand the parent, one can see the cylinder011 attached to the parent.

Comment: I've got to check what I'm saying better... For some reason, when I append the child, then append the parent separately, the parent carries the child with it.  I'm a bit confused.  To duplicate: Create new blend, library append child, unlock it and move it away.  Library append the parent, and the child comes along.  This seems normal if truely parent and child; but, I can't see how they're linked. (sigh... still a noob.)

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to use a simple plane as boolean operand here - which is by definition **not** manifold (a manifold surface must be closed, since all its edges have to have two and only two faces). Behavior of booleans in this case is never really ensured…

Also, your 3DView only shows objects enabled for rendering, and your 'ObjA' object is disabled for rendering, so it's completely hidden from 3DView.

Other than that, I see no issue with this .blend, if there are please be more specific.

Comment: Thank you. 
I have revised the file such that all objects are selectable, renderable and visible in 3d View.
I have also made solidified the plane such that now it is a manifold.
The Problem remains: Boolean operator _Difference_ is behaving like _union_

Answer (score 3):

I could confirm the odd behaviour and found a way to work around it.

The coil shaped object has two edge loops that exists in the same space, the one on top and the one in the bottom.

So I selected the bottom one (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + right click) and moved it up a tiny tiny amount. <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>z</kbd> <kbd>0.001</kbd>

Now the boolean modifier works.

[image: bottom edge loop nudged up]

[image: bottom loop in coil]

Comment: You beat me to it ;)

Comment: Thank you for confirming the behavior (so that I can post a bug). How did you find which is the problematic loop?
Did you have to change just one vertex or the whole coil? 
Thanks again.

Comment: I changed the bottom loop of the whole coil. See new screenshot.

Comment: @Ben, manifold also means no self-intersection. It can also help to reduce the amount of geometry and use e.g. array after boolean.

Comment: Same problem with simper geometries: In [this example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3xskN0a8UruVGluTC1oNHNkemM/view?usp=sharing) I am unable to substract ObjA from ObjB. See how Difference, Union, and Intersect - all perform unexpectedly.

I still don't have a method of solving these.

Comment: I run into this issue all the time.  It can be seen in simple objects like two cubes.  If I make a cube 2x2x2 and duplicate it, and move it 2 along the X axis, I will have two cubes with two faces that are in the same space.  Ideally, when one wants to join two objects, this would be the perfect solution as they'd make one 4x2x2 object.  However the boolean operator won't allow this; and I also think it's a bug because theoretically the two faces should be non-existent after the boolean union, but mathematically 1&1=1 which would leave an inner face, and therefore non-manifold.

Comment: Either move it a bit, as suggested in this answer, or make the Parent a tiny bit smaller at both ends, or make the child a tiny bit bigger.  I always make the part I'm subtracting bigger than the thing I want to subtract from.  If your shrink the Parent cylinder so it exists between the top and bottom (Z) it will make your thread cuts perfectly. So, duplicate the child, move it up and join them (or boolean union) making sure threads align, then it should work perfectly for removal.