# How can i bake an animated and extruded curve to a mesh animation?

Tags: animation, mesh, modifiers, text-object

I have a text object that i want to reveal with a kind of handwriting effect. My plan is to animate an extruded curve which i want to use as a boolean operator on my original object.

[image: Animated extruded curve]

How can the animated mesh (blue) be exported or converted so i can use it later on the red text? Right now i cannot select the blue mesh as an operand in the boolean operator.

Answer (score 4):

The blue mesh isn't a real mesh it is generated from a curve so it can't be used in the Boolean modifier ( and other mesh dependent modifiers ) , also the text object( red one ) is a curve so it can't be used in the Boolean modifier.

You can convert  the curve into a mesh :
 - select the curve and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and choose ***Mesh from Curve*** 
***Note:*** beware after converting to a mesh you loose the curve editing options ( including this animation )

The animation you have can be replicated using the build modifier  on the converted mesh :

[image]

now you can have both the animation and the Boolean modifier on this mesh

Comment: The build modifier produces unpredictable results and the resulting mesh causes "Cannot exectue boolean operation". Even with removed double vertices and fixed normals.

Comment: @dequid the build modifier follows the vertices order ( which created first ) , for the boolean modifier  [see this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5148/5113)

Comment: yes, and that vertex order is my problem. If i check _fill caps_, the polygons on the caps are builded first in the build modifier. As i understand, i need a closed mesh for the boolean modifier to work properly. Any ideas?

Comment: it seems that the vertices order can't be changed, also the boolean will need non self intersecting mesh where this is not , can you give more details on the main goal you are trying to achieve maybe there's another way?

Comment: As you can see in my first animation, i want to have a text mesh (red) which is revealed over time like it was 'written by hand'. So at the _'T'_ for example the lower stroke from top to bottom then the lower stroke from left to right and so on. What i also thought of: Is there a way to import a vector animation into Blender (i know this is a separate question)?

Comment: @dequid for the vector animation i have no idea ( i know that you can import SVG ) , is your scene more complex cause i can achieve the effect with material nodes ( no boolean needed ) if you want ?

Comment: No, for the text part it is just that simple. Would love to see the material approach since i dont know how to make parts of an object invisible based on its material.

Comment: here is [the example file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/191/) if that's what you need i'll edit the answer to include it

Comment: Goes definitely in the right direction, except the transparent BSDF does not work, when the text object is extruded (non covered areas get black instead of transparent).

Comment: this is weird  , i'll see if i can fix this

Comment: @dequid here is [another file see](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/197/) if it does it, I had to reverse the animation and change the shaders order

Comment: @Chebdou it works. Thanks a lot. If you make it an answer, i'll upvote and accept. Cheers.