# Modelling a sphere with holes on it

Tags: modeling

I am a hobby Blender user and I would like to model a robot. I want to model its face with a hole for the eyes. Something like on this picture:

### [image: Example]

First I wanted to solve this problem with a boolean modifier.
[image: boolean modifier]

---

My second try was modelling it manually.
[image: modelling manually]

---

I also tried to use shrinkwrap modifier but none of them were really well. So I am looking for an efficient solution which does not destroy the topology. I really hope someone has an awesome idea.

Comment: [This page](http://topology-guides.tumblr.com/) my give you some ideas.

Comment: I don't think you should delete those parts where eyes should be. Instead, model it so topology itself to form this shape, extrude it a bit outwards and proceed to modeling eyes themselves.

Comment: Check this answer out, it may be just what you are looking for??? [Answer on how to cut shapes from Blender.stackexchange.com](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/why-wont-the-boolean-modifier-work-properly)

Comment: How about you take the first try you have there, select the edge loop ( select an edge on the extremity, hit **Ctrl-E**, select **Edge loop** from the menu.  Press **Shift+C** Cursor to selected.  Hit "." to scale by centre.  Then, hit "E" with all your edges selected, and then "S" to scale the new inner loop.  This more or starts what Mr Zak mentioned.

Comment: I tried something quickly by creating two spheres, one of them without hole. Then shrinkwrap the other sphere on the intact one. Then remove a few faces to make a hole roughly the shape you want. After this, apply subsurface modifier and deform the holes with proportional editing on. I don't think it destroys the topology. If you want the result to be very symmetric, you can use the mirror modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not necessary to combine these two models in the first place unless there is a specific reason why you would not model them separate.

Assuming there is a reason, I would do the following:

1. Start with a cube
2. Add and apply subdivision surface modifier level two
3. Shift-Alt-S + 1-Key in edit-mode to make the resulting shape a sphere
4. Shape the model according to you needs by insetting and extruding the corresponding faces.
5. Add subdivision surface modifier but don't apply this time unless you want to add even more detail the current topology does not cover.

   [image: Model after step 5]

   [image: Model after applying second subd modifier and adding more detail]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to destroy the topology it means you need to do it by hand. But you model has to many points so it is impossible.
One solution could be to use a sphere with olny 64 or 32 points, then use the boolean, then redo the topoly point by point so it can be nice, and In Fine apply subsurf so your shepere look more smooth.