# Boolean modifier "Cannot execute boolean operation"

Tags: modifiers

I'm currently making a Rook chess piece on Blender. I've been trying to use the boolean modifier to subtract a part of the chess piece. The first application of the boolean modifier worked. However, as I was on my second attempt, I got the message "Cannot execute boolean operation".

[image]

I've already searched online for any possible solutions, but nothing seemed to have worked with mine. Could anyone help me with this?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is pretty difficult to say without having the .blend to play with. Could you upload it? Also, this could be of some help to you: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5140/cannot-execute-boolean-operation-when-subtracting-several-spheres-and-cylinder

Comment: can you use this link to upload so that no one need to register somewhere else ? thanks http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You have a ring of faces which have no surface on the top of the tower. If you 'remove doubles' it will work... of course the creases are lost... but you can add an edge split modifier at the end

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/boolean-modifier-not-working?rq=1