# Boolean Modifier not working at all

Tags: modifiers

The Boolean Modifier isn't working at all, just leaving these weird lines:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boolean Modifier not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/boolean-modifier-not-working)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5140/cannot-execute-boolean-operation-when-subtracting-several-spheres-and-cylinder/5148#5148

Comment: I tried both solutions and none of them worked

Comment: It looks the bit where the intersection occurs is non-manifold (a single plane), if so this is probably the problem